# Animate tab in Tab Bar when scroll/slide tabs

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using [flutter_animator 3.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animator) to implement animation when tapped on Tab Bar. Everything is doing fine but when scroll/slide to next Tab. The animation wouldn't work and I've tried with  tab controller listener as well as listening to tabcontroller animation, but it wouldn't trigger the immediate playing of animation like when the `TabBar` is selected.

Edit:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/apror.jpg as shown in here, when I tap on the Tab Bar, it animates nicely, while when I scroll/slide to another Tab, it doesn't work properly & instead it animates also the previous Index's tab. I would like to achieve the same way the animation plays (on tap) when scroll/slide to another Tab.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter_animator/flutter_animator.dart';

class Playground extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlaygroundState createState() => _PlaygroundState();
}

class _PlaygroundState extends State<Playground> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  late final List<GlobalKey<AnimatorWidgetState>> _animKeys;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this)
      ..animation!.addListener(_animationStatus);

    _animKeys = List.generate(
      4,
      (index) => GlobalKey<AnimatorWidgetState>(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animKeys.forEach((key) {
      if (key.currentState != null) {
        key.currentState!.dispose();
      }
    });
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _animationStatus() {
    if (_tabController.animation!.status == AnimationStatus.forward) {
      print('Going forward');
      _animKeys[_tabController.index].currentState!.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _tabs = List.generate(4, (index) {
      return ClipRRect(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minWidth: 100,
            maxHeight: 55,
          ),
          child: Tada(
            preferences: AnimationPreferences(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
              autoPlay: AnimationPlayStates.None,
            ),
            key: _animKeys[index],
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: TabPainter(
                animation: _tabController.animation!,
                index: index,
              ),
              child: Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Tab $index',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          'Tab Bar',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        bottom: TabBar(
          onTap: (index) => _animKeys[index].currentState!.forward(),
          controller: _tabController,
          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 2.0),
          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          tabs: _tabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: List.generate(
            4,
            (index) => FittedBox(
                  child: Text('Tab $index'),
                )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Animation<double> animation;
  final int index;
  final tabPaint = Paint();

  TabPainter({
    required this.animation,
    required this.index,
  });

  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Size size) {
    if ((animation.value - index).abs() < 1) {
      final rect = Offset.zero & size;
      canvas.clipRect(rect);
      canvas.translate(size.width * (animation.value - index), 0);
      final tabRect =
          Alignment.bottomCenter.inscribe(Size(size.width, 3), rect);
      canvas.drawRect(tabRect, tabPaint..color = Colors.black);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: Animation is working, but the last animation is also animating , can you clarify what are you trying to archive?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh edited my question. I would like to achieve the same result of when tab is tapped when I'm slide or scrolling the tab to another tab.